# replace text file into code using python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to ask is there any way for me to replace some comment inside a text file or source code using Python? I have created a marker between comment and I need to replace all the old comment to the new one (the marker is `/*<NeedtoReplace>*/` and `/*<\NeedtoReplace>*/`). I have already saved the new as `newComment.txt` and would like to generate a script that can read the new comment and replace it into the old inside source code.  There have approximately more than 4+ source code inside different folder that I need to change the comment or header comment. Using python 2.6.6

```
/NeedtoReplace/
Copyright bla bla bla 
Few lines of comment.
Other comment.
bla....
/\NeedtoReplace/

code
```

Comment: Please can you confirm the markers you are using e.g. `/NeedtoReplace` until `/\NeedtoReplace`? Your text implies there are also `/*` and `*/`?

Comment: Sorry for wording and formatting. First time use this and just explore about the wording. so the markers that i've set is /*<HEADER>*/ for opening and ending is /*<\HEADER>*/

Answer (score 1):

You need a few steps, firstly open your new comment file and store the text. Next scan through your folder for suitable source files, e.g. `*.cpp`. For each file, open it and read the whole file in. Next use a regular expression substitution to replace the text. Next close the source file and reopen it for writing. Then write the updated text back to the file:

```
import glob
import re

with open('newComment.txt') as f_comment:
    comment = f_comment.read()

for filename in glob.glob('*.cpp'):
    with open(filename) as f_source:
        source = f_source.read()
        source = re.sub(re.escape(r'/*<HEADER>*/') + '.*?' + re.escape(r'/*<\HEADER>*/'), comment, source, flags=re.S)

    with open(filename, 'w') as f_source:
        f_source.write(source)
```

Note, this will work for all `.cpp` files in a single folder. If you need to walk an entire directory tree, you can change to using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'll try to applied it first.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you:

> string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
>
> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

[7.1. string — Common string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try first.